# SOLIDWORKS file to PDF via eDrawings API not generating pdf without data (Image)

Tags: pdf, solidworks

Am using bellow tutorial to use convert .slddrw (Solidwork) to pdf using eDrawing API by using bellow link

https://www.codestack.net/edrawings-api/output/print-to-pdf

Am able to generate pdf file but data (image) is not coming in the pdf file.

This is the .slddrw file viewing in edrawing [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eczlh.png)

After export to batch pdf coming like bellow [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO3Pd.png)

I Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Am able to find solution for this. we need to add the EMvPrintType.eScaleToFit the code like bellow.

m_Ctrl.Print5(false, fileName, false, false, true, EMVPrintType.eScaleToFit, 1, 0, 0, true, 1, 1, pdfFilePath);